# I'm almost finished with this logical proof but I can't figure out the very end! Could someone take a look? :)

Tags: proof-verification, first-order-logic

It's an FOL proof
[image: It's an FOL proof (you can take a look here)]
 Thank you so much!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On line 3 you should assume $F(a)$

Remember you are setting up an $\exists$ Elim on $\exists x \ F(x)$ (Indeed, line 7 should refer to premise 2, not 1) and so you should take the formula $F(x)$ and substitute a constant for the $x$.

Comment: Hi Bram28! I took your advice about F(a) but I'm still not sure how to finish off the proof

Comment: @user726371 Note that after assuming Fa, you can simply *infer* Fa v Ga using v Intro